# set div full screen even when scroll the page

Tags: html, css

I want to set `#bodyHider` full screen. I tried this code:

```
#bodyHider{
    position:absolute;
        width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    z-index:10000;
}
```

the HTML code:

```
<div id="bodyHider"></div>
```

It worked, but when I scroll down, I see `#bodyHider` is at the top of the page. I want this div whole screen even if I scroll the page.

Comment: How about just making the position `fixed` and setting `top: 0; left: 0;`. That ought to do it.

Answer (score 8):

This is what you want.

```
#bodyHider{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    z-index:10000;
}
```

Comment: @Swister It would be nice to approve my answer so everybody knows it was that simple.

Comment: Switching from position absolute to fixed, solved my problem.

Comment: position: fixed is indeed the way to go, not absolute.

Answer (score 1):

A little example, with the fixed position.

**CSS**

```
html, body { 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; max-width: 100%;
}
body { overflow-x: hidden; }

#bodyHider{
  position:fixed;/* Put the position fixed */
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:#000;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
  z-index:-1;
}

#main {
position:relative:
height:auto;
width:100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="bodyHider"></div>
<div id="main">
Your content.
</div>
</body>
```